# When was the first time Star Wars EU explicitly mentioned people having sexual relations?

Tags: star-wars

Answering [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/46173/when-did-luke-skywalker-lose-his-virginity-in-the-eu/46182#46182), it got me to thinking: at some point Star Wars EU went from full-on PG rating for A New Hope, to explicit sexual relations implied (or heck, almost shown) in "[Star Wars: Agent of the Empire](http://static1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120501040643/starwars/images/thumb/5/58/Cross_interrogates_Dahlis.jpg/220px-Cross_interrogates_Dahlis.jpg)" comic.

**What was the first time (publishing order) when the idea was introduced in EU that depicting or at least explicitly mentioning sexual relations between characters was OK**? (as opposed to lovey dovey mushy romance with kissing being the raciest things two characters did in Ep IV-VI, <sub>leaving aside Leia's slave costume</sub>).

Comment: It was a long, long time ago, in a Galaxy far, far away...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First one I remember was X-Wing series' book 4 ("The Bacta War") released on February 6th 1997. It references Corran and Mirax being lovers:

> “Couldn’t sleep?”
>   Corran started, then turned and smiled at the black-haired, dark-eyed woman standing in the bedroom doorway. “I guess not, Mirax. I’m sorry I woke you.”
>   “You didn’t wake me. Your absence awakened me.” She wore a dark blue robe, belted at the waist with a pale yellow sash.
>   Mirax raised a hand to hide a yawn then pointed at the silver cylinder in his right hand. “Regretting your decision?”
>   “Which one? Refusing to join the Jedi Knights or”—he smiled—“or hooking up with you?”
>   She raised an eyebrow. “I was thinking of the Jedi decision. If you have reservations about the other decision, I can relearn how to sleep alone.”
>   He laughed, and she joined him. “I regret neither. Your father and my father may have been mortal enemies, but I can’t imagine having a better friend than you.”
>   “Or lover.”
>   “Especially lover.”

Not exactly HBO level explicitness, but worth a consideration.

Comment: There were some fairly explicit discussions of Corran's romance with a Selonian officer; as well as Erisi's attempt at seducing Cooran in Book 2 of X-Wing series, complete with discussions of Kuatian upper-crust mating customs.

Comment: Related to my last comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/23019/17807

Comment: Hold on, what about those other two pilots in the X-Wing Series - the human guy and the Bothan woman? I forget their names, but they pretty explicitly discussed the possible negative consequences of interspecies pairings. And the human at some point mentions to a nosy enquirer regarding the physical relationship with the Bothan that their "parts fit together well." It's been years since I read those books though - was my feverish teenage imagination dreaming that up, or was it real? Can't remember if it was before or after Book 4, either, but it was obviously more explicit than the above.

Answer (score 7):

Leia and Han are strongly hinted to have sex during *The Truce at Bakura*. Han tries to woo Leia with a romantic dinner and asks Chewie to set the ambience in the *Millenium Falcon*'s cargo bay, only to discover that Chewie, apparently not understanding the subtleties of human courtship, has put a big pink bed in the cargo bay. Han tries to apologise, Leia kisses him and throws him on the bed, the chapter ends. They are unlikely to have been baking cookies back there. That pre-dates the already accepted answer's publication.

Comment: This seems less explicit than the question was aiming at, but a good data point

Comment: It's more explicit in the aftermath, to be honest. Han shows up to work with a huge grin on his face, with Chewie chuckling, him hurriedly fixing his shirt, etc.. Basically, the 'I've just gotten laid, and this is how we show it in a family-friendly sit-com' scenario.

Comment: you know what I'll say. Quote or it didn't happen :)

Comment: Where would Chewie **find** a pink bed?

Comment: @Oldcat: Stacy from Pink 5.

Answer (score 1):

### November 12, 1976

A reference to sexual activity is mentioned in the narration of *Star Wars: From the Adventures of Luke Skywalker*, released six months before *A New Hope*.

> "You sense only a part of the force, Darth," Kenobi murmured with the assurance of one to whom death is merely another sensation, like sleeping or making love or touching a candle.

While not referring to the activity in-universe, the phrasing of "merely another sensation" implies that the narrator doesn't see anything wrong or unusual about it.

*[Tales from Mos Eisley](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tales_from_the_Mos_Eisley_Cantina)*, released August, 1995 also contains [a short story](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Nightlily:_The_Lovers%27_Tale) *centered* around sexual relations.

Here's the story's blurb:

> ***Feltipern Trevagg,*** a ruthless Gotal who's on a hunt for a beautiful alien he'd love to bed and a legendary Jedi Knight he'd gladly kill.

> He succeeds at the former.

Comment: I'm wondering should I flag your reply as inappropriate... >.>